# how to encode password in javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, passwords, special-characters

I have password textbox which allows the user to enter any type of characters with the password. But registration fails when the user uses a password like say 'mypass@676/my&pass/my%pass' but when other characters are used he is able to register. Is it due to password not getting encoded in the front end?

I posting the registration url to my register service since it is a url if the password is mypass@676 the system takes only upto mypass and ommits the other characters and as a result it is failing.

My code in javascript is like this,

`data+= "&password="+$(formID).find('input[id=password]').val();` and this will go to my service as it is.

***Issues:***

1. If i encode my password in javascript say my password is
   "my%passw" so when i encode "my%25pass" and during login which i
   should give?
2. Ok if i encode again during login what will happen
       to my existing users passwords will it get encoded?

Comment: Could you post a bit more about what is happening to the password in between? Is this a database issue? Parsing issue?

Comment: Unlikely. Try to print the password on the server side to test it.

Comment: Can't you send it via `POST` instead of `GET` ?

Comment: @christy it is post method.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
data += "&password=" + encodeURIComponent($(formID).find('input[id=password]').val());
```

By the way, `input[id=password]` can be simplified to `input#password`.

Comment: will this change affect my existing users. How will the password gets stored now in db?

Comment: @Oscar No, this does not affect the string your script receives. Passing `mypass%40676%2Fmy%26pass%2Fmy%25pass` results in the string `mypass@676/my&pass/my%pass`.

Comment: @Oscar The term *encoding* is maybe a bit misleading since you normally don't have to *decode* in your PHP script. It is more like *escaping*.

Comment: Ok but when i saw my ajax post the password parameter has "my%passw" but something in backend makes it fail i guess..